# Haskell Parsing Recursion and Maybe

Tags: parsing, haskell, recursion, functional-programming

I'm trying to write a parser in Haskell.

This parser take a string (example: "abc def") in parameter and return a Maybe (String, String).

> Maybe (String, String)
>
> First String get characters while it's number or letter.
>
> Second String get the rest

In this example, I want to return Maybe ("abc", " def").

```
parseString :: String -> Maybe (String, String)
parseString "" = Nothing
parseString expr = case isString expr of
                Just (char, rest) -> fmap (char:) (parseString rest)
                Nothing -> Just ("", expr)
```

> isString return :
>
> Maybe (Char, String) -> Char = first character, String = rest / Nothing if isn't a letter or digit.

The problem, I can not return the rest of my String in the maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be in

```
fmap (char:) (parseString rest)
```

Now, `(char:)` is a function `String -> String`, so `fmap (char:)` becomes `Maybe String -> Maybe String` (or its generalization to another functor). However, `parseString rest` is not a `Maybe String`, it is a `Maybe (String, String)`.

So, we need to adapt `(char:)` to work on the first component of that pair. I'd try

```
fmap (\(res,rest2) -> (char:res, rest2)) (parseString rest)
```

(By importing `first` from [`Data.Bifunctor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html#v:first) or [`Control.Arrow`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:first), that can be written as `fmap (first (char:)) (parseString rest)`, but that's not that important.)

Comment: What is `char:` if I may? I do not understand the colon.

Comment: @Evgeny `(expression symbol)` is a _section_, a shorthand for `(\x -> expression symbol x)`, so `(char:)` means `(\x -> char : x)`, the function which prepends `char` to the input string `x`.

Comment: Oh, the `:` is from list contructor, a kind of point free prepending at head of list? Thanks for explaining to me, @chi, it looked like a mystery.

Comment: @Evgeny Yes, it is one of the list constructors (the other one being `[]` for the empty list).